# How to customize auto-increment in mysql to start from a default value

Tags: mysql, database

[image]How can i create a customized auto increment in mysql database using phpadmin I want the auto increment to start from something like id_0001, id_0002, id_0003 not the default 1,2,3.How to auto increment and auto_generate the row"tagId" following that same sequence

Comment: You want to move from an efficient integer column to an inefficient char column? or is this just for display purposes.

Comment: Display where exactly? Read [ask] and create a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [use a `VIEW`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-view.html) to get the ID values like this based on the id column:

```
-- creating the VIEW
CREATE VIEW view_name AS 
SELECT CONCAT('id_', RIGHT(CONCAT('0000', id), 4)) AS custom_id, * FROM table_name;

-- using the VIEW
SELECT * FROM view_name
```

You shouldn't change the default behaviour of the the auto increment to get a id value like `id_001`. A id value should be a numeric value.

Comment: so please where does this goes I am using PhpAdmin